S3 SignatureDoesNotMatch even when content disposition set
I'm using the following code with the AWSSDK.S3 nuget package:
public static string GetPreSignedURL(string filename, string displayFilename)
{
    GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new();

    request.BucketName = BucketName;
    request.Key = filename;
    request.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24);
    request.Headers.ContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=" + displayFilename;

    return client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
}

There are no errors running this on the the uploaded file to get a presigned URL, which is returned:
https://mydomain.ewr1.vultrobjects.com/86af3c37-2098-4301-90fc-f79c4c2d559d?AWSAccessKeyId=TWQVOAXAG4K34ITQPM7V&Expires=1719736648&Signature=vJ7ruIafjpEzH1gilFQUOYqnfOM%3D
Now I add the same content-disposition on the end so it will download with the filename I want:
https://mydomain.ewr1.vultrobjects.com/86af3c37-2098-4301-90fc-f79c4c2d559d?AWSAccessKeyId=TWQVOAXAG4K34ITQPM7V&Expires=1719736648&Signature=vJ7ruIafjpEzH1gilFQUOYqnfOM%3D&response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=test1.txt
But this gives an S3 error if I try to follow the link:
<Error>
  <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
  <RequestId>tx00000080074260b914ed7-00667fc9c3-67874bae-ewr1</RequestId>
  <HostId>67874bae-ewr1-us</HostId>
</Error>

Any idea of how to set this up properly? Thanks.

Does signature include the attached file?

Instead of Headers, you need to use ResponseHeaderOverrides to have the content disposition show up in the response from the request.  And don't modify the returned URL, nearly any modification you make to it will necessarily change the signature.

Legend! @AnonCoward you hit the nail on the head. Thanks for your help.
